# How to find all Java method calls and given parameters in a project programmatically?

Tags: java, static-analysis

I have a multilingual web application that gets all of the translations from a single object, for example `lang.getTranslation("Login")` and the object is responsible for finding the translation in an xml file in the user's language.

What I'd like to do is a script / custom static analysis that outputs all the missing translations and translations that are no more used in the application. I believe I should start by programmatically finding every call to the getTranslation method and the string parameter, storing the data in a special structure and comparing it to all the translation files.

Is there a library that will allow me to do this easily? I already found [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) but I can't use it to read the parameter values. I also tried `grep`ping, but I'm not sure if that's a robust solution (in case there will be a call to another class that has a getTranslation method). I know Qt has a similar mechanism for finding translatable strings in the code, but that's a totally different technology..

I'm asking this because I'm quite sure there's a good existing solution for this and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: If you have all places in the sourcecode where `lang.getTranslation()` gets called, you could do a "call" search - just use your IDE for that. Otherwise it is hard to determine if something is NOT used. You could maybe add a logging mechanism to find out what IS used and compare that to the list of available texts to filter out those which haven't been used in a while ...

Comment: If you want to do it programatically: Read each `.java` File in your project directory. Read each line and check if `lang.getTranslation()` is a substring of the line. If so, `regex` out the String Parameter and add it to an ArrayList or something similar. Then compare it to a list of all String parameters. Though that's reinventing the wheel, to be honest.

Comment: DaDaDom: I have done that in my IDE and I do have a logging mechanism for missing translations. However, I can't cause all possible strings and error messages at once and I don't want to search for the Strings manually. I'm a lazy programmer and lazy programmers don't do stuff by hand ;)

Comment: If you only pass static strings like hardcoded `"Login"` then you could use a big enum instead to ensure a translation exists (compiler support). You could then compare the enum with the translation file. If you want to compose the translation keys dynamically via conventions, it may be annoying to use enums and text is more flexible but also more fragile.

Comment: Just have to point out that the built-in method for multi-language support is java.util.ResourceBundle. That will throw an exception if it can't find an entry, although there's no good way to find "extra" entries.

Comment: I'm actually using the ResourceBundle and all the missing entries end up in a log file. BUT. It only works run-time. I would have to do everything possible in the software and trigger all possible errors, which is a no-go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here's how I did it. Not the optimal solution, but works for me. I created a utility program in Java to find all the method calls and compare the parameters to existing translations.

1. Find all classes in my project's root package using the [Reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) library
2. Find all `getTranslation` method calls of the correct class in the classes using the [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) library and create a list of them (contains: package, class, row number)
3. Read the appropriate .java files in the project directory from the given row until the ';' character
4. Extract the parameter value and add it to a list
5. Find the missing translations and output them
6. Find the redundant translations and output them

It took me a while to do this, but at least I now have a reusable utility to keep the translation files up to date.